# NVIDIA Parallel Nsight and OpenCL

Tags: debugging, opencl, nvidia, nsight

I'm little confuse with NVIDIA Parallel Nsight and OpenCL, can anyone confirm me that it is possible to debug OpenCL code using NVIDIA Parallel Nsight 1.5 or 2.0RC?

Answer (score 2):

Currently it is not possible to debug OpenCL kernels with Parallel Nsight yet. Parallel Nsight 2.0 (the latest release as of Jun 2011) only supports the debugging of CUDA kernel. However OpenCL debugging is one of the features that is likely to go into the product in future releases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, I've did it my self, the only problem is that you will need two computers connected to network, having two identical video cards. One will be executing your kernel step by step(due to this fact the graphical adapter won't be able to display results, the display will stall) this is where the second computer comes in to play, it displays results in Visual Studio like you were debugging ordinary program.

Personally I found NVIDIA Parallel Nsight as a useless tool. Any kernel debugging can be done via adding additional argument to a kernel and outputting any subject data there.

Comment: I tried put -g argument on Apple platform, but it gave me message abou unsupported argument.

Comment: I don't understand what is apple platform is all about, you can use NPNS only under windows...

Answer (score 1):

Parallel Nsight **2.1** include API for trace OpenCL 1.1 now
@see http://nvidia.com/object/parallel-nsight.html